# Backrefrence in mod_rewrite Rewrite_rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

what's the use of back references in Rewriterule in mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

See this for excruciating details:

[Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask/214521#214521)

Backreferences are used to address specific match-groups in `RewriteRule` segments.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(2008|2009)/(.*)$   /newblog/$1/$2
```

(2008|2009) is a reference, and $1 is the backreference. Same for (.*) and $2. As you can see, they're used for URL rewriting. See the "RewriteRule matching syntax" section of the answer I linked to.